# How do I pass the whole http URL to a stored procedure in an asp.net API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

My task is to create a asp.net API in which:

- User posts XML to my APi endpoint
- API Passes the whole of the XML directly to a stored procedure
- Stored procedure returns some XML back to the API for the user

Example call to api:

```
https://localhost:44308/api/OrderProcessing?<?xml version="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?><Param1>abc123</Param1><Param2>5</Param2><Param3>123456</Param3>etc.. etc
```

I've found many examples of calling a procedure from asp.net and all of them show the XML nodes being parsed into parameters to pass to the stored procedure:

```
usp_myproc @param1 =abc123, @param2  =5, @param3 =123456 etc.
```

I can't find out how to pass the xml as a single string as shown below EG

```
    usp_myproc @param1 =xml version="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?><Param1>abc123</Param1><Param2>5</Param2><Param3>123456</Param3>etc.. etc
```

So far I have the following code which, which of course just passes the first parameter, eg.  `usp_myproc @param1` not the whole string

```
    namespace OrderProcessingApp.Controllers
    {
        public class OrderProcessingController : ApiController
        {
            [HttpGet]
            public IHttpActionResult StockOrder(string param1)
            {
               StockFinderEntities sd = new StockFinderEntities();
               var results = sd.fn_ProcessOrder(param1).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help very gratefully received

Comment: What problem are you having adding the value of `param1` as a parameter to the stored procedure?

Comment: param1 is just the first node of the xml document I want the whole xml document

Comment: why have stored procedure parse xml when c# does much better job.

Comment: @jdweng I'm sure you are correct, but that is not what has been specified

Comment: I see. The user is not passing xml, it is individual query string parameters. It sounds like you need to generate xml, using those values. Is that your question? Do you know what structure you want? Your example calling the procedure is not an xml document or even a fragment.

Comment: Besides the lack of actual XML in your example above. Passing your URL string directly to your sql dB is a big nono. You are setting up your app for sql injection

Comment: The example you reference is showing you the correct thing. You should be "massaging" your user request into your sql calls, passing a requested url directly could bring about big problems in the future

Comment: @Crowcoder You are correct I was trying to show brevity, the xml would be like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Param1>abc123</Param1>
  <Param2>5</Param2>
  <Param3>123456</Param3>
  etc
I will update my question

Comment: So your question is actually how to generate that xml document? Or is it how to convert it to a string so you can set it as a parameter value?

Comment: @Crowcoder, Ok I've updated my question, hopefully that is clearer.Yes convert it to a string to send to the stored proc

Comment: There's a lot unclear here. You appear to have an unorthodox approach. Questions: 1. So you have an endpoint that should receive XML in the query string (are you really sure about this, since you mention "POST", so I hope it's in the body? What _exactly_ is your endpoint supposed to support in input, POST, GET, query string, request body? Does the query string have a key, or is it entirely XML? 2. So you're supposed to pass the XML to a SQL function, which parses it, queries the database and returns the entities corresponding to the XML parameters? Can you change this?

Comment: And 3. Do you really want to return your database entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack here and quite some information missing, see also my comments on your question. There are answerable parts in your question though, but things are far from optimal.

If I get this straight, you want this:

- An API endpoint that accepts GET requests with the query string comprising entirely of an XML string.
- In this action method, pass the XML string to a SQL user defined function.
- This function parses the XML, does its thing, and returns zero or more records.
- These records are then returned as a list to the caller.

So first things first, you've got to read that XML. Your query string appears to have no keys (it directly starts with `?<xml...>`). Is this intentional, or an oversight in creating this question? Are you really sure you want to read XML from the query string, or can you change this design?

If you can change it, the idiomatic way would be to use query string parameters, which are then bound to your action method parameters:

```
// GET .../StockOrder?param1=42&param2=Foo&param3=Bar
public IHttpActionResult StockOrder(string param1, string param2, string param3) { ... }
```

Assuming you really want to read the raw query string as XML, as opposed to a single parameter:

```
// GET .../StockOrder?xmlString=<xml...>
public IHttpActionResult StockOrder(string xmlString) { ... }
```

Then you need no parameters at all:

```
// GET .../StockOrder?<xml...>
public IHttpActionResult StockOrder() 
{ 
    string xmlString = this.Request.RequestUri.Uri.Query.Value;
    ...
}
```

So now you have the XML string, and you'll pass it to a user defined function in your database. While Entity Framework will pack it up in a SQL parameter, at least you'll be safe from SQL injection here:

```
// GET .../StockOrder?<xml...>
public IHttpActionResult StockOrder() 
{ 
    string xmlString = this.Request.RequestUri.Uri.Query.Value;

    if (xmlString?.Length > 0)
    {
        // Remove the question mark from the start
        xmlString = xmlString.Substring(1);
    }       

    var results = sd.fn_ProcessOrder(xmlString).ToList();
    ...
}
```

But this is still far from optimal! The caller could pass invalid XML, which would only be detected by SQL Server, which is way too late in the process. Or worse, it could be a specially crafted XML that SQL Server would choke on (like an XML bomb), or worse (executing arbitrary code contained within the XML). So I would not be a fan of sending user input in the form of XML directly to a SQL Server, no.

The optimal way would look like this:

```
public class GetStockOrderModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Param1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Param2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Param3 { get; set; }
}


// GET .../StockOrder?param1=42&param2=Foo&param3=Bar
public IHttpActionResult StockOrder([FromUri] GetStockOrderModel model) 
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // ...
    }

    var records = sd.fn_ProcessOrder(model.Param1, model.Param2, model.Param3).ToList();

    var models = records.Select(o => new
    {
        FieldToReturn = o.Field1,
        OtherField = o.Field2,
        // ...
    }).ToList();

    return Ok(models);
}
```

Here, you have a model to bind to and perform validation, the database function is altered to accept actual parameters instead of XML, and a model decoupled from the database is returned.

Now if you say you cannot alter the function, because other applications call it, you might still be able to. The function you call exists of two parts: one that reads the parameters from the XML, and the other that executes the query using those parameters.

So you keep the original function, and let it call the new one once it extracted the parameters. You can then also call that new function, using the parameters you have in code.

And really, you don't want to pass user XML to your database server. Sure, it'll only be called by trusted parties, you'll say. But is everyone at those parties to be trusted? And don't they ever make mistakes?

So if you really don't want to change anything about the endpoint nor the function, and you're going to use that fourth (or second) code block, at least read the XML string in your controller, parse it, extract the parameters, validate them, and rebuild the XML from a safe template string, or something like that.

Because to ASP.NET, that XML is treated as a plain old string, so you have none of its validation or security measures.

Comment: I am heavily in your debt.... Thank you
Your advice makes complete sense, I've gone back to my manager with your thoughts and he accepts what you say, so I shall implement code as you advise. Although I will still need to pass the whole string as-is through to the procedure for audit purposes
I have a further question though ...
Using the method you suggest, how do I cope with the xml containing multiple orders.
For example <ordernumber>12345</ordernumber><Customer>Ford</Customer><order><cartype>Car 1 Red</cartype><cartype>car 2 blue</cartype></order>